# How to discern video details from Linux Live CD

Tags: linux, graphics-card, kernel, livecd, x-windows

I was having trouble getting X.Org to work with the video card in a recently aquired laptop, so I decided to try to probe around the configuration of a Linux Live CD to figure out how to set up my kernel.  I chose the Sabayon 5.0 Live DVD because it was the only one that I could find that was the same or newer than the 2.6.32 kernel I have installed on the laptop right now.  Of course, the DVD booted right into GNOME without issue, unlike the hangs and crashes that I had been getting.  So, I want to figure out what kernel driver this Live DVD is currently using, but I don't know how to.

`hwinfo` doesn't shed any light on the matter, and `lspci -vnn` doesn't list a driver for my video device, though both methods correctly identify that I have an Intel 855GM video processor.  How can I find out this information?

Answer (score 1):

Try the X.org log, usually in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.